# Derivation of photon propagator rearranging of equation

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, greens-functions, propagator

i have a question regarding the derivation of a formula. Currently i'm reading in Ryder's Quantum Field Theory Ch.7 where he derives the covariant form of Maxwell's equations (natural units):
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu \left( \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu \right) = j^\nu$$
in the next line he states, that this formula can be written as:
$$\left( g_{\mu \nu} \Box - \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \right)A^\mu = j_\nu$$
to identify the Photon Propagator / Greens Function.
Can someone explain me, how i get from the first to the second equation? My naive approach would be using $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu = \Box$ and thus:
$$\partial_\mu  \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu = \Box A^\nu - \partial_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu.$$
But here it ends, i tried using the relation $\partial_\mu A^\mu = \partial^\mu A_\mu$ and using the the metric tensor $g_{\mu \nu}$ to lower/higher the indices. But i can't get aboves equation.

Comment: Before you even begin to do any calculations, always check that the indices make sense. Looking at the first equation you wrote down you find that on the left hand side $\nu$ is not contracted however on the right hand side  $j^\mu$ the index $\mu$ is not contracted while $\nu$ does not appear. Replacing $\mu$ with , $\nu$ here allows for quite easy calculation of what you want. (Note that in the second line the index is not only wrong but also at the wrong position)

Comment: ok thank you, i edited the question, because it was misleading. I just want to now, how to do the rearrangement to get from equation 1 to equation 2.

Comment: $\partial_\mu \partial^\nu = \Box$ is not correct (and doesn’t make sense because of inconsistent indices).

Comment: Thanks, there was also another typo in my last equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct you can do this simply using the definition you used and rasing/lowering indices:
Take:
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu \left( \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu \right) = j^\nu$$

Now write $A^\nu = {\delta}_\mu {}^\nu A^\mu$. I.e. just insert a delta operator. Now with this (after distributing the partial and replacing $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu = \square$:

$\partial_\mu \left( \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu \right) = \square {\delta}_\mu {}^\nu A^\mu -\partial_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu  =  ({\delta}_\mu {}^\nu \square -  \partial_\mu \partial^\nu) A^\mu = j^\nu$ . Now we lower the $ \nu $ on both sides using the metric and your done after contracting $\delta$ with the metric.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about using the delta operator.